# how to use nginx builtin parameters $hostname

Tags: nginx, hostname, built-in

The [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24args) says that we can use many built-in parameters. But when I used `$hostname` in the *nginx* conf file, it complains in the error log:

> 2014/09/10 07:55:53 [emerg] 18902#0: invalid return code "$hostname"

Comment: How do you try to use it? Show.

Comment: And do you really need it? Not `$host` or `$http_host`?

Comment: location = /jump_goto {
internal; 
return $hostname;
}

Comment: And what do you want it to do? Probably you should read docs http://nginx.org/r/return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because hostnames are not status codes. What you most likely are looking for is:

```
location /jump_to {
    internal;
    return 302 http://$arg_hostname/;
}
```

But this is an educated guess. Specify your goals if are still suck with this.